# First day of week from HTML5 Intl API

Tags: javascript, html, date, internationalization, ecmascript-intl

Is there a way to get the first day of the week (Sunday or Monday for most countries) from the HTML5 internationalization API?

The spec can be found [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-402/1.0/). I would be surprised if it's not somehow disclosed, but I can't seem to find where.

Comment: It looks like `Intl` has been designed to follow ISO 8601, which only allows Monday as first day of week :(

Comment: I'm fan of `Intl` as implemented in PHP: a wrapper for ICU. My expectation was that browsers would also just use the ICU library from the Unicode Consortium to implement their own `Intl` extention. But it seems everybody implements their own? A workaround is to output [`getFirstDayOfWeek()`](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classicu_1_1Calendar.html#aa95d4e17ea169d0388a3a18489e67da0) in JSON to your own HTML5 app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The official vanilla API for retrieving this is `Locale.prototype.getWeekInfo()`, or the currently more supported `Locale.prototype.weekInfo` (Firefox does not support either!):

**Small note: Firefox does not support either!**

```
// New API, currently only in Deno, Bun & Safari Technology Preview (2023-10)
new Intl.Locale('en-US').getWeekInfo()

// "Old" API, available in Chrome, Edge, Opera, Node & other Chromium-based browsers
new Intl.Locale('en-US').weekInfo
```

which will return an object like:

```
{
    firstDay: 7,      // First day of the week is Sunday
    minimalDays: 1,   // First calendar week of the year must have at least 1 weekday
    weekend: [6, 7]   // Weekend is Saturday and Sunday
}
```

---

Examples for other cultures: (`new Intl.Locale('<locale>').weekInfo`)

Germany `de-DE`:

```
{
    firstDay: 1,      // First day of the week is Monday
    minimalDays: 4,   // First calendar week of the year has at least 4 weekdays
    weekend: [6, 7]   // Weekend is Saturday and Sunday
}
```

Egypt `ar-EG`:

```
{
    firstDay: 6,      // First day of the week is Saturday
    minimalDays: 1,   // First calendar week of the year has at least 1 weekday
    weekend: [5, 6]   // Weekend is Friday and Saturday
}
```

Uganda `sw-UG`:

```
{
    firstDay: 1,      // First day of the week is Monday
    minimalDays: 1,   // First calendar week of the year has at least 1 weekday
    weekend: [7]      // Weekend is Sunday only
}
```

Brunei `ms-BN`:

```
{
    firstDay: 7,      // First day of the week is Sunday
    minimalDays: 1,   // First calendar week of the year has at least 1 weekday
    weekend: [5, 7]   // Weekend is Friday and Sunday
}
```

---

Polyfilling this is possible, but I recommend the excellent `date-fns` library until the `Temporal` API arrives in most browsers, which has similar data (without weekend information) available for currently 93 locales:

```
import { enUS, deAT, ar, hi } from 'date-fns/locale'

enUS.options.weekStartsOn          // 0 <- careful, 0 = Sunday
enUS.options.firstWeekContainsDate // 1

deAT.options.weekStartsOn          // 1
deAT.options.firstWeekContainsDate // 4

// Arabic
ar.options.weekStartsOn            // 6
ar.options.firstWeekContainsDate   // 1

// Hindi
hi.options.weekStartsOn            // 0
hi.options.firstWeekContainsDate   // 4
```

---

Small Note - the spec has changed from a property to a function, since all browsers/runtimes implemented `weekInfo` as a getter which would always return a new object, and cause this unintuitive behavior:

```
const swedish = new Intl.Locale('sv');
swedish.weekInfo === swedish.weekInfo  // false
```

Comment: Some info I found on `weekInfo`: it is going be wonderful when it exists, but the TC39 proposal for [intl-locale-info](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-intl-locale-info) is currently at stage 3 and [not available yet](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_builtins_intl_locale_weekinfo) in firefox and some active safari versions. I wasn't able to find a polyfill.

Comment: yes I found this very usefull too , but why no one polyfilled it yet ?

Answer (score 6):

`Intl` doesn't have an API to access this sort of calendar information yet.  It's possible it may [add support for doing so in the future](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1287677), but right now you're out of luck.

Comment: Tracker: https://github.com/tc39/ecma402/issues/6